# SSHD Failed to retrieve unit: Connection time out

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, connection, ubuntu-16.04

After upgrading from ubuntu 14 to ubuntu 16 **sshd service** is having problems. It keeps to long to connect, sometimes fails to connect etc. 
When i try to restart sshd service most of the times i get an error message:

```
myuser@myserver:~$ sudo service sshd restart
Failed to retrieve unit: Connection timed out
Failed to restart sshd.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status sshd.service' for details
```

When i check systemctl status the error is:

```
myuser@myserver:~$ systemctl status sshd.service
Failed to get properties: Connection timed out
```

It seems like the problem is not only for the sshd service because it does the same thing also for other services. For example when i am installing or uninstalling anything from the server i get:

```
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Sounds like a systemd (or possibly dbus) problem.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers.  Have you rebooted since the upgrade?  Maybe try `systemctl daemon-reexec`.